# Is RGBRast included with .NET 3.5 SP1?

Tags: .net, directx

I need to use the RGBRast software renderer for a DirectX application I'm developing. Currently I'm just including the DLL with my install.

I have read a few places that it is also included with .NET 3.5 SP1. Is this true? If so, where is the DLL located?

---

This redistributable component can be downloaded from:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=57d03491-6c49-4429-bff7-130408b5f410

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, included since 3.0, no doubt to support WPF.  Evidence [is here](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2009/05/07/9595739.aspx).  Copied to c:\windows\system32\rgb9rast.dll

Comment: For me it was named rgb9rast_2.dll. I wonder if there's a reliable way to load this DLL without specifying its filename?

Comment: A better reference might be http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2008/07/13/8729636.aspx. He refers to %WINDIR%\system32\rgb9rast_2.dll

Comment: I have loaded this software rasterizer using: IntPtr rasterizer = LoadLibrary("rgb9rast_2.dll");

Comment: On an unpatched Windows 7 system the file was named rgb9rast.dll.

Answer (score 1):

```
    // Perform a LoadLibrary of the Microsoft Software Rasterizer...
HMODULE hRast = LoadLibrary(szPath + CString("\\RGB9Rast.dll") );
if(!hRast) {
    hRast = LoadLibrary(szPath + CString("\\RGB9Rast_1.dll") );
    if(!hRast) {
        hRast = LoadLibrary(szPath + CString("\\RGB9Rast_2.dll") );
        if(!hRast) 
            return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is similar to the code found here: http://svn.alleg.net/svn/Allegiance/branch/FAZR6/src/engine/D3DDevice9.cpp